# How to find how far something has traveled. trig help

Tags: trigonometry

Sandra is riding the Ferris wheel, and her height can be modeled by the equation $H(t) = 25 \cos (\pi/14) t + 31$, where $H$ represents the height of the person above the ground in feet at $t$ seconds.

Part 1: How far above the ground is Sandra before the ride begins?

Part 2: How long does the Ferris wheel take to make one complete revolution?

Part 3: Assuming Sandra begins the ride at the top, how far from the ground is the edge of the Ferris wheel when Sandra's height above the ground reaches a minimum?

*I just got thrown in this online class, with no real instruction. Whats the equation to use? I would put my work in, if i knew where to start

Comment: What have you tried so far? Notice that before the ride begins she should be at time $t=0$ (I assume).

Comment: this question very likely comes from an old ap calculus exam.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**.

Part $1$: Sandra is at the bottom of the ride right before the ride starts, that corresponds to $t=0$ seconds. How do you find her height at $t=0$?

Part $2$: Notice that the function $H(t)$ is cylic because the trig function $\cos x$ is cyclic. It takes $\cos x$ $2\pi$ to complete a full cycle. So how long does it take $\cos\left(\frac{\pi \,t}{14}\right)$ to complete a full revolution?

Part $3$: The minimum of $\cos$ is $-1$. So what is the minimum of $-25 \cos x$? Then what is the minimum of $25 \cos x + 31$? So how close does Sandra get to the ground?